# mit jdm. dulden

Tags: word-usage, meaning, meaning-in-context

Aus Goethes „Die Leiden des jungen Werther“:

> Frau M. ist sehr schlecht; ich bete für ihr Leben, weil ich mit Lotten dulde.

Was bedeutet der Teil „weil ich mit Lotten dulde”? Diese Verwendung von „dulden“ ist mir unbekannt.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Meines Erachtens bezieht sich das „dulden“ auf den Zustand von Frau M. und bedeutet:

> […] weil ich (gemeinsam) mit Lotte leide.

Referenzen: Im Wörterbuch der Gebrüder [Grimm](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&hitlist=&patternlist=&lemid=GD05428) fängt der Eintrag unter „dulden“ wie folgt an:

> DULDEN, *leiden, ertragen,* […]

Weiter unten:

> *mit gelassenheit, gleichmut, ergebung widerwärtiges ertragen.* a) *transitiv.* man duldet was man nicht ändern kann.

Auch im [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/dulden) wird „leiden“ als Synonym aufgeführt (in der Bedeutung von u. a. durchmachen, durchhalten, ausgesetzt sein, bewältigen).